The code is executed only once through ota in esp32?
I have a question :
When I update the firmware through ota, it is reset once by the esp program and the new program received from the server is executed, but after the micro power is disconnected and connected once, the same firmware update program is executed again. Any new programs previously downloaded will be lost.
this is my code :
#include <Arduino.h>

#include <WiFi.h>

#include <FS.h>
#include <SPIFFS.h>
#include <esp32fota.h>


// esp32fota esp32fota("<Type of Firmware for this device>", <this version>, <validate signature>, <allow insecure https>);
esp32FOTA esp32FOTA("esp32-fota-http", 1, false, true);
const char* manifest_url = "http://test.technosense.co/fota.json";

void setup_wifi()
{
  delay(10);
  Serial.print("Connecting to WiFi");

  WiFi.begin("wolf","12345678"); // no WiFi creds in this demo :-)

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  esp32FOTA.setManifestURL( manifest_url );
  esp32FOTA.printConfig();
  setup_wifi();
}

void loop()
{

  bool updatedNeeded = esp32FOTA.execHTTPcheck();
  if (updatedNeeded)
  {
    esp32FOTA.execOTA();
  }

  delay(2000);
}

filesystem partition(s):
enter image description here
What is the solution to this issue?
I do this with the library
https://github.com/chrisjoyce911/esp32FOTA
I tested and this was the result.

Welcome to Stack Overflow.. For us to help you, provide the expected [mre]. We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points. This allows testing suggestions against your data and desired output.
DO NOT post images of code, links to code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.

Could you add the configuration of your filesystem partition(s)?

Yes, it was added

Does the new downloaded program contain the OTA section as well? It should, I guess. Be sure it does not trigger the update again, or at least print some debug messages to signal which firmware is currently running

The code work as per the way you wrote it, is the update available? sure it is, but that doesn't tell you what is the firmware version the device has against the version available on the server. You need a mechanism to check the version before starting the OTA. I don't the FOMA API, I wrote my own CloudOTA to do that.
